# Set culture and ui-culture in appsettings.json (asp.net core localization)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-mvc

I have asp.net core application which I want to localize and translate (v 1.1.0). I want the source code to support both english and norwegian deployments, and I found this could be a startup.cs configuration

```
RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-US"), new CultureInfo("nb-NO") },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("en-US"), new CultureInfo("nb-NO") },
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("nb-NO")
};
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

However I want to have only one culture and one ui-culture for each deployment, so I hoped to find out a way to set culture and ui-culture in appsettings.json or enviroment variables. Is it possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure.

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
    "SiteLocale" : "en-US"
}
```

`Startup.cs`:

```
var locale = Configuration["SiteLocale"];
RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo(locale) },
    SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo(locale) },
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(locale)
};
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems so simple when you have told me how.