# jQuery Date validation works on localhost, but not on Azure

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, date

I'm relatively new to MVC. I have created a new MVC ASP.NET Core 2.0 project in VS 2017 and managed to get things going fine until I added a DateTime field.

Model/View

```
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime QDate { get; set; }
```

I have tried it in Edge, IE, Chrome and Firefox on the localhost and all works as expected.

However after uploading to Azure the Date validation says

> The value '22/09/2017' is not valid for Date

And only works if I use the MM/dd/yyyy format!

This is my first post, so if you need any more information I will respond quickly.

Many thanks

Comment: You need to set the culture of your app (e.g. in the `web.config` file) to one that accepts dates in that format

Comment: Have you tried setting `<globalization culture="[yourculture]" uiCulture="[yourCulture]" />` in web.config?

Comment: because in your development environment you have set the clock and timeformat to your local culture. But in azure its always set to mm/dd/yyyy and time is always utc time

Comment: There is no web.config file for this type of application! So where, and how, would I set the culture information? An example or link would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Ok, found this [Set culture and ui-culture in appsettings.json (asp.net core localization)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336783/set-culture-and-ui-culture-in-appsettings-json-asp-net-core-localization) which I got to work.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this hardcoded shorter method in startup.cs:

```
        var locale = "en-GB";
        RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(locale),
            SupportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo(locale) },
            SupportedUICultures = new[] { new CultureInfo(locale) }
        };
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

This works just fine for what I am doing. Thanks for you help